# how i can this log in system with yahoo,twitter,facebook etc

Tags: authentication, openid, php4

in many sites i can see
[alt text http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/4633/15494794.gif](http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/4633/15494794.gif)

how i can do that
is must tell every company or what?

Answer (score 1):

It's [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID). You can implement it in PHP easily by looking for PHP OpenID Libraries/Classes.

See http://openid.net/add-openid/add-getting-started/ to get started on developing authentication with OpenID.

Unfortunately, Facebook and Twitter has a complete different set of authorization api and thus you cannot use OpenID for Twitter and Facebook. Instead you can use their API.

Comment: can you give my the twitter api